# Syntax error on official Ethereum ERC20 Code?

Tags: solidity, truffle, erc-20

I copy and pasted the code found here: https://www.ethereum.org/token
into a file called TokenERC20.sol

When I run

```
truffle compile
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Expected "contract", "import", "library", "pragma", "using", comment, end of input, end of line, or whitespace but "i" found.
    at peg$buildStructuredError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:177767:12)
    at Object.peg$parse [as parse] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:181366:11)
    at Object.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:89808:23)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:57847:36
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:50141:5
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:66021:16
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:75933:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:50126:7
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:96942:5
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:75838:16
```

Anyone know what could be causing this?

*EDIT*
The problem appears to be here:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

interface tokenRecipient {
   function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public;
}

contract TokenERC20 {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;
```

If I comment out the interface and every line that uses it then it compiles fine. Is there some problem with how the interface is declared?

Comment: Which editor are you using to edit the file? Can you save your file as utf8 and try again?

Comment: @Ismael I'm using Atom and at the bottom of the file it says its utf8 already

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for the help, i posted an edit to the question. I found the line that is causing the problem, but im not sure how to rewrite it?

Comment: What's your Solidity compiler version? It seems that it requires 0.4.11 or higher (the pragma notwithstanding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interface contracts were introduced in Solidity version [0.4.11](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.11):

> Version 0.4.11
>
> This release ... adds interface contracts and implements some
>   additional safety checks.
>
> Features:
>
> ...
>
> - Support interface contracts.
>
> ...

Compilers older than 0.4.11 give the error you report.

Check your compiler version, but your `pragma solidity ^0.4.8;` doesn't look promising.